# how to quit scroll bar in openlayers info-popup

Tags: popup, gis, openlayers

this is my code

```
Info.newInfoPopUp = function (obj) {
    var table = createInfo(obj);
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
    obj.name, 
    obj.lonlat, 
    new OpenLayers.Size(), 
    '<table class="info-table popup">' + table.html() + '</table>', 
    null, 
    true, 
    obj.closeCallback
    );
    popup.minSize =new OpenLayers.Size(300,155);
    popup.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(800,200);
return popup;
};
```

the popup appears sometimes whith a vertical scroll-bar

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenLayers.Size class constructor should have parameters width and height.
Try this:

```
var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
    obj.name, 
    obj.lonlat, 
    new OpenLayers.Size(100,100), 
    tablHtml, 
    null, 
    true, 
    obj.closeCallback
);
```